# webpack build failed because of uglifyJsPlguin

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I try building `webpack.config.js` file. My command is `webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --colors`. But my building is failed because of ulgifyJsPlugin. When I removed uglifyJsPlugin in `webpack.config.prod.js`, building is successful, but not working when there is UlgifyJsPlugin. I want to minimize my codes by webpack - like remove console.log codes and other unnecessary codes. Plus, I'm using webpack 1.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: [path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js')],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'bundle.js', 
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader', 
        exclude: [nodeModulesPath]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./style')
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    packageAlias: 'browser'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new AppCachePlugin({
      exclude: ['.htaccess']
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
      }
    })
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Make sure you [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) is installed...as stated [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/), UglifyJS is a peer-dependency for this plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `plugins` section to include the plugin like this:

```
plugins: [
        ...,
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
            comments: false,
            sourceMap: false,
            mangle: true
        })        
    ]
```

This works for me.

Also, were you sure to do `npm i --save`? Make sure you've added the plugin in your `node_modules`.